# Blockly - Reference Error: functions not defined

Tags: javascript, eval, blockly

I'm attempting to use Blockly to do a "make your own game" sort of thing, and for the most part it works. However, when trying to run code generated (by Blockly's own pre-defined function generators) by declaring a function and calling it, I consistently get told that the function isn't defined, no matter what it is or what it contains.

I'm grabbing and running the code like so:

```
var code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode();
try{
    eval(code);
} catch (e){
    alert(e);
}
```

Which is how the demos provide on Blockly generate code. I've also echoed the code out elsewhere in the page and it looks right to me:

```
function whatINameIt() {
    //code I give it
}
//rest of code
```

Is this something to do with how eval works? The only thing I can think of is that for some reason it's "evaluating" the function code but not adding it as something callable. If that's the case, is there an alternate way I should run the code string Blockly gives me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are creating an [`infinite loop`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/installation/code-generators#infinite_loops). To solve it, you will have to add the following lines as the documentation of `Blockly` says:

```
window.LoopTrap = 1000;
Blockly.JavaScript.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP = 'if(--window.LoopTrap == 0) throw "Infinite loop.";\n';
var code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspace);
```

Also, if you have created [`custom Blocks`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/custom-blocks/overview#define_a_block), as it seems in your question, make sure that you are returning the code that you are creating in all of them. If you do not return it, the `workspace` will not know that these `Blocks` want to do whatever.

It would be great to help you if you provide the `Blocks` code that you are creating/using and the code that you are retrieving from your other function.